# Reaching json-file in res/raw folder from Java code Android

Tags: java, android, json

I am having some trouble trying to figure out how to reach my quiz.js (JSON-file) from within my assets folder in the Android project.

This is the method i use to load questions from a JSON file:

```
public ArrayList<Question> loadQuestions() throws IOException, JSONException {
    ArrayList<Question> questions = new ArrayList<Question>();
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    try{
        // Open and read the file into a StringBuilder
        //InputStream in = mContext.openFileInput(mContext.getResources().getString(R.raw.quiz));
        //InputStream in = mContext.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.quiz);
        InputStream in = mContext.getAssets().open("quiz.js");
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        StringBuilder jsonString = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            // Line breaks are omitted and irrelevant
            jsonString.append(line);
        }
        // Parse the JSON using JSONTokener
        JSONArray array = (JSONArray) new JSONTokener(jsonString.toString()).nextValue();

        // Build the array of crimes from JSONObjects
        for(int i=0; i< array.length(); i++){
            questions.add(new Question(array.getJSONObject(i)));
        }
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e){
        // Ignore this one; it happens when starting fresh
    }
    finally{
        if(reader != null){
            reader.close();
        }
    }
    return questions;
}
```

This is the JSON file json.js:

```
[
{
    "imageURI": "100",
    "question": "Hva betyr skiltet?",
    "answers": [
         "Farlig sving til venstre",
         "Farlig sving til høyre",
         "Blah..",
         "Blahh.."
     ],
    "correct": 0
},
{
    "imageURI": "101",
    "question": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...",
    "answers": [
         "String 1",
         "String 2",
         "String 3",
         "String 4"
     ],
    "correct": 2
}
```

]

This is from the activity where i try to use the data from the JSON

```
public class QuizActivity extends Activity {

private ArrayList<Question> questions;
private QuizJSONSerializer mSerializer; 

private static final String TAG = "QuizActivity";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_quiz);


    // This is where i get the loadQuestions from
    mSerializer = new QuizJSONSerializer(getApplicationContext());

    try{
        questions = mSerializer.loadQuestions();
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        questions = new ArrayList<Question>();
        Log.e(TAG, "Error loading questions: ", e);
    }

    ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.question_image);
    iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.mdpi_farlig_sving);

    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.question_text_view);
    if(questions == null){
        tv.setText("Something wrong with the array!");
    }
    else{
        tv.setText(questions.get(0).getQuestion());
    }

    Button b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.option_one);
    b1.setText("String 1");

    Button b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.option_two);
    b2.setText("String 2");

    Button b3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.option_three);
    b3.setText("String 3");

    Button b4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.option_four);
    b4.setText("String 4");
}
```

}

Seems like the JSON file never gets loaded in because the code from my exception always run.

Is there something missing in the JSON file?

Any good advice?

Comment: `mContext.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.quiz)` should work ... IndexOutOfBounds is not connected with this code ...

Comment: `IndexOutOfBounds` ? Are you sure it's related to this piece of code?

Comment: Actually, now i am not sure anymore, because now i moved the JSON file to the assets folder and tried Ragaisis solution in the post below. That didnt work either.

Comment: `getAssets` and `res/raw` are not the same thing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an asset folder by using:

```
InputStream input = context.getAssets().open("yourJSON.json");
```

and you will reach your file.

Answer (score 1):

You should create assets folder and put your file there. Then you can use this to reach your file

```
InputStream is = context.getAssets().open("departments.json");
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not bundle the JSON into the app by using the assets folder? It is an asset after all, not a raw resource.